# How to buy SSL Certificate to use with SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, encryption, ssl

I have a thick client written in VB6 that connects to an Sql Server 2005 Database.  I want to secure the connection by using SSL between the client and DB.
I've looked at these links for details on "how to" configure it.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067%28SQL.90%29.aspx

**Question**

If I want to buy an SSL certificate to use in this scenario, do I just buy the standard SSL certificate sold for websites?  I would imagine so, but I want to make sure.

I guess SSL certificates are standard and can be utilized anywhere as long as the client and server know how to use that protocol.

But in case I do buy a standard SSL certificate, what do I mention as far as my website domain address etc? - Since I'm going to use it between thick VB6 client and SQL Server 2005, I wasn't clear how to go about this.

Is there any other (easier) way of securing the connection between a thick client and Sql Svr DB?  My requirement is to only make the connection secure....it doesnt have to be SSL.

Thanks
Amit

Comment: May be a better question for http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a certificate trusted by the client. You can choose between using one of the trusted certificate authorities (VeriSign, Thawte, GlobalSign) or deploy a root of trust on your clients. The DB client validates the certificate the same way all SSL certificates are validated, by verifying the Subject against the name used by the client to connect.

Given that a normal DB deployment you *know* what your clients are, then it makes a lot of sense to pre-deploy the certificate used on the client and save yourself the cost of a true SSL system trusted authority signed cert.

If your DB clients are open ended and can add themselves at will, then it doesn't make sense to have them connect to the DB directly. Point is that there must be a deployment step (a Setup) that adds the new client to be trusted on the back end, and this step can also deploy your own root certificate as a new trusted root on the client, or, if the client is paranoid about adding an entire root, just the certificate used by the server as a trusted cert.

Comment: Thank you for the information.  I used a self-generated certificate using makecert and imported it on both client and server side as under trusted root certificate authorities.  So your info definitely helped.  It's a different case that I'm not able to get the secure connection working :(...probably doing something incorrectly.  But thanks for info..I know I'm in the right direction.